# Why we need to do mutation after crossover?

Tags: genetic-algorithms

I am reading about genetic algorithms.

In the genetic algorithm process we perform crossover *and* mutation.

However, in the crossover, we *already* produce offspring, so then why do we also need to perform mutation?

What is the use of mutation after crossover? An example would really help me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question doesn’t meet a Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange guideline.

Comment: @Pluviophile Could you state what guideline you are thinking of and what might help the OP to improve the question. As far as I can see, the question is on topic and specific, but a little open ended e.g. "what is the use, explain with an example". I will edit/tidy the question for presentation.

Comment: I have tidied the text of the question. I tried to keep as many of your original words and phrases as I can. If you disagree with my edit you can roll it back, or if you want to add or clarify anything further, please use [edit]

Comment: @NeilSlater. Aw thank you so much sir, i really appreciate you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we apply the mutation operation after generating the offspring?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/9236/why-do-we-apply-the-mutation-operation-after-generating-the-offspring) I voted to close your question as a duplicate, but given that others voted to close it as off-topic, that's what it ended up being marked as. @DennisSoemers, could you please fix this?